# contact form 7 wordpress dropdown

Tags: java, php, html, wordpress, plugins

I just installed `contact form 7` plugin - everything is working fine
I am receiving mails but I have issue I created one **drop down** which have different options like `1 2 3 all 3 option` have different emails is that   possible that when user select option 2 so mail will go to only that email.
I have tried all the things but nothing is working.

```
<h4> School  *
 [select* menu-873 include_blank "Quartier Militaire SSS (Girls)" "Shrimati Indira Gandhi SSS(Boys)" "Floreal SSS" "Royal Curepipe" "Forest Side SSS(Boys)" "Forest Side SSS(Girls)" "France Boyer De la Giroday SSS" "Emmanuel Anquetil SSS" "Beau Bassin SSS (Girls)" "John Kennedy" "Ebene SSS(Boys)" "Ebene SSS(Girls)" "Queen Elizabeth College" "Dunputh Lallah SSS" "Mootoocoomaren Sangeelee SSS" "Riviere Des Anguilles SSS" "Sookdeo Bissoondoyal State College" "St Aubin SSS" "Swami Vivekananda SSS" "Bel Air SSS" "Camp De Masque State College" "Rajcoomar Gajadhur SSS" "Sebastopol SSS" "Sir Leckraz Teelock SSS" "Marcel Cabon SSS" "Manillal Doctor SSS" "Bon Acceuil State Collge" "Piton Sate College" "Beekrumsing Ramlallah SSS (Mapou SSS)" "Ramsoondar Prayag SSS" "Simadree Virahsawmy SSS" "James Burty David SSS" "Droopnath Ramphul State College" "Prof Hassan Raffa SSS" "Terre Rouge SSS" "Royal College Port-Louis" "Pailles SSS" "Lady Sushil Ramgoolam SSS" "Triolet SSS" "Pamplemousses SSS" "Port louis North SSS" "Hamid Goolam Issac SSS" "G.M.D Atchia SSS" "Adolphe De Plevitz" "Frank Richard SSS" "Seeneevassen SSS" "Goodlands SSS" "Sharma Jugdambi SSS" "Sir Abdool Razack " "Maurice Cure State College" "Gaetan Reynal SSS" "Palma SSS" "Quatre Bornes SSS" "Sodnac SSS" "Vacoas SSS" "Seewa Bappoo SSS" "Bambous SSS" "Belle Rose SSS" "La Gaulette SSS" "Phoenix SSS" "Sir Abdool Raman Osman State College" "Swami Sivananda SSS" "Dr Regis Chaperon SSS"]</h4>
```

this is the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1

Selectable Recipient with Pipes

select tag would be something like that:

```
[select menu-873 "Quartier Militaire SSS (Girls)|email1@example.com"
            "Shrimati Indira Gandhi SSS(Boys)|email2@example.com"
            "Forest Side SSS(Girls)|email3@example.com"]
```

If you insert a pipe (‘|’) character in the middle of the option value, only the part before the pipe will be open to the outside, and the part after the pipe will be used for mail replacement.

Step 2:
Go to “Mail” Tab in your form and put the tag ( in my case it is [menu-873]) inside the To field

```
**Note : Please don’t get confused seeing the Red Bordered warning**
```

Comment: where i put the tag in which field can you tell me the name of that field kindly .thank you

Comment: Go to “Mail” Tab in your form put the tag inside the To field https://prnt.sc/pjz9o9

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectable recipient with the pipe in the dropdown:

```
School * [select* menu-873 include_blank "Quartier Militaire SSS (Girls)|email1@example.com" "Shrimati Indira Gandhi SSS(Boys)|email2@example.com"]
```

Then use `[menu-873]` in the mail settings.

Please check [here](https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/) for more information.

Comment: [menu-873] where to enter this code in mail setting i entered and check every where in the mail setting but its not working

Comment: @HSM007p in the "To" field under the  "Mail" tab. http://prntscr.com/pjyvwd

Comment: thank you so much bro its now working fine.. but in the back end its showing syntax error but its working fine should i ignore the warning

Comment: @HSM007p yes ignore the warning in the Mail tab. Also, please approve the answer.

Comment: how to approve i dont know im new here

Comment: @HSM007p There will be a checkmark below the answer. You can click it to approve answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @HSM007p You have approved the other answer, not mine. You can only approve one answer and can upvote multiple answers.